# Unix - removing duplicate headers from file

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I have a file (result.txt) which is having few duplicate header lines, I want to retain only one header line and remove all other duplicates (refer desired output). I tried using sort -u, uniq, sed and all other options but I couldn't able to get the desired output. Could someone help me on this.

```
cat result.txt
Metric              date_sk  date_sk -7 
----------------  ----------  ---------- 
Test1            2015-10-19  2015-10-12
Metric                 date_sk  date_sk -7 
----------------  ----------  ---------- 
Test2            2015-10-19  2015-10-12  
Metric               date_sk  date_sk -7 
----------------  ----------  ---------- 
Test3            2015-10-19  2015-10-12

Desired output:
Metric              date_sk  date_sk -7 
----------------  ----------  ---------- 
Test1            2015-10-19  2015-10-12
Test2            2015-10-19  2015-10-12 
Test3            2015-10-19  2015-10-12
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed '3,${/^Metric/d;/^---/d}' file
```

Output:

```
Metric              date_sk  date_sk -7 
----------------  ----------  ---------- 
Test1            2015-10-19  2015-10-12
Test2            2015-10-19  2015-10-12  
Test3            2015-10-19  2015-10-12
```

If you want to edit "in place" add sed's option `-i`.

Comment: Above command works as expected, could you please help in your command how you are retaining 1st line.

Comment: These commands (search and delete) only affects the range of line 3 to last line (`$`).

Comment: oh.. ok. got it. Thanks.